# Use keys of one type to create type containing keys of another type

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, typescript-eslint

I have an interface of types as such:

```
interface MyInterface {
  Name1: { userId: string }
  Name2: { bookingId: string }
}
```

I have a type below that accepts an object of type `{ [key: keyof MyInterface]: boolean }`:

```
type TProperties<T extends Record<keyof MyInterface, boolean>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: P extends keyof MyInterface ? Pick<MyInterface, P> : never
}
```

But when I try using it as such:

```
TProperties<{ Name1: true }> // Error <large obj redacted> is not assignable to type 'Record<keyof MyInterface, boolean>'.
```

Where am I going wrong in the above?

Answer (score 0):

You constrained `T` to be a `Record<keyof MyInterface, boolean>` which means that `T` must have *all* the keys of `MyInterface` and not just some of them. We can change that by using `Partial`.

```
type TProperties<T extends Partial<Record<keyof MyInterface, boolean>>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: P extends keyof MyInterface ? Pick<MyInterface, P> : never
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwFgAoZZAOTgFsIBGALkOQFcBnaTAEybbClABzZAF9S5KrQBMTAsgBGAe0UBrId178ho0mJKlSYdAAcUAFQAKURaahhgENgB4zyCAA9IILm2QW4dsBwADZOAEoQCIpQXE4qEOiKMGhYOLCIEAA0CsrBEHAgAHzFyAC8hOLkyADaFsigyPGJyWYAukx1Hl4+jQlJKdiQ6fgA-H7ACCpOGIO4GdkWhchMIBAAbtC6BiRGpshmjmBl+1Y20PaOTnKS9Ez8LCgihUA)

Though I am not really sure if that type does what you expect it to do. Maybe you were looking for something like this?

```
type TProperties<T extends Partial<Record<keyof MyInterface, boolean>>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: MyInterface[P & keyof MyInterface]
}
```